# React.js version conflict between modules using Mesh.js and use-react-screenshot

Tags: mesh, reactjs

I’m using a Mesh.js starter template that’s using React.js 18 version.  I also want to utilize a component called use-react-screenshot that is react.js version 17.  Unfortunately the component will not load because of the mismatch.  What’s the best practice to resolve the version conflicts?